# udev to trigger a systemd service when the attribute changes?

Tags: systemd, udev

i have a buggy wifi intel Ax200, frequently drops connection on 5Gz{no beacon heard bug}.

i want to create a udev rule based on the "sys/class/net/wlan0/operstate"  {down|up} values.

udev rule i created based on the what i read online and manuals as below "91-wifi.rules"

```
KERNEL=='wlan0', SUBSYSTEM=='net', ATTR{operstate}=='down', RUN+="systemctl restart iwd"
```

using iwd service to restart when connection goes down.

i have tried running by reloading it,but not working.

Comment: If you run `udevadm monitor` do you actually see any events when the wifi changes state?

Comment: Apparently ATTR change is not detected in monitoring.